# XML -> Smarty foreach and if condition

Tags: xml, smarty

I have some small problems with code of smarty template for results . The problem is next this code is **working** but doesn't give me 500 results for this if condition. The code is looking like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<source>
<publisher>CMS</publisher>
<publisherurl><![CDATA[{$GLOBALS.site_url}]]></publisherurl>

    {foreach from=$listings item=listing}

        {if $listing.Country =='USA' || $listing.Country == 'UK' || $listing.Country == 'Russia'}

    <job>
        {$listings.foreach.Country.total} Total results
        <title><![CDATA[{$listing.Title}]]></title>

        <date><![CDATA[{$listing.activation_date}]]></date>
        <referencenumber><![CDATA[{$listing.id}]]></referencenumber>
        <url><![CDATA[{$listing.listing_url}]]></url>
        <company><![CDATA[{$listing.user.CompanyName}]]></company>
        <city><![CDATA[{$listing.City}]]></city>

        <country><![CDATA[{$listing.Country}]]></country>

        <description><![CDATA[{$listing.JobDescription|strip_tags:false} {$listing.JobRequirements|strip_tags:false}]]></description>
        <salary><![CDATA[{$listing.Salary.value} {foreach from=$listing.SalaryType item=list_value name="multifor"}{tr domain="Property_SalaryType"}{$list_value}{/tr}{if !$smarty.foreach.multifor.last}, {/if}{/foreach}]]></salary>

        <jobtype><![CDATA[{foreach from=$listing.EmploymentType item=list_value name="multifor"}{tr domain="Property_EmploymentType"}{$list_value}{/tr}{if !$smarty.foreach.multifor.last}, {/if}{/foreach}]]></jobtype>


    </job>

        {/if}    


    {/foreach}    

</source>
```

If you see or know answer please post it below, thanks!

Comment: what do you mean 500 results? What do you get and what would you expect?

Comment: This means that this loop is working and give me a results in xml file for this countries but not 500 results as I put in admin (there is php function which work well) because there are all countries have posts and loop go up to 500 times but give results just for this countries which are in this condition.

Answer (score 0):

do a var_dump in php on $listings. How much records do you have>

Comment: I have aprox. 5000 results. What you mean with this var_dump ?

Comment: var_dump prints nicely aarray, objet or whatev u want to check. Just try do var_dump($listings); in php file.
About your problem, chceck how many records apply for this
        {if $listing.Country =='USA' || $listing.Country == 'UK' || $listing.Country == 'Russia'} it must be this